# MacOS 10.15.4 dnsmasq doesn't work properly when listening on lan IP address

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, homebrew, dns

I have a dnsmasq set on my Mac to provide DNS lookup service to lan computers and Mac itself.The main conf script is `listen-address=127.0.0.1,192.168.1.2` where `192.168.1.2`is Mac's lan IP address. Strangely, dnsmasq worked fine on localhost, but not response when requested from other computers from lan.

I tried to test it by `dig` command saying `dig google.com @192.168.1.2`, it said:

```
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Whereas, to the localhost `dig google.com @127.0.0.1`, it worked.

But, the `ping` command returned

```
icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
```

Which means the address is online. I use `sudo brew services start dnsmasq` to make it can listen on such addresses.

How to debug this issue?

Comment: Here, the very same setup works flawlessly! How did you setup the other hosts in the LAN to access the Internet?

Comment: @klanomath Hi, I just set DNS to 192.168.1.2 on other hosts. But that's not the key part of the issue, I cannot come through the test from current host as mentioned. So, I am a little confused.

Comment: I meant: do you share Internet to the other hosts in your LAN via Mac(192.168.1.2)? Or are all other hosts in the same network (192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0)?